# conversion of magento 1 into magento 2

Tags: magento2

I was using fetch_assoc() method in magento 1 .
I want to convert it into Magento 2 . there is no fetch_assoc() method in magento 2.

```
if(is_object($result))
{   
    while ($resultsArray =$result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        if(empty($data))
        {
           $data[] = array_keys($resultsArray);
        }
        $data[] = $resultsArray;

    } var_dump($data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure my proposed solution is useful for you or not but the best approach to fetch data in Magento 2 is based on `Models` and `Collections`.

**Step 1:** Firstly, you have to create a `Model` file in your module

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;

class Data extends AbstractModel
{   
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('<Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model\ResourceModel\Data');
    }
}
```

**Step 2:** Create `ResourceModel` file in your custom module

```
<?php
namespace <Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model\ResourceModel;

use \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class Data extends AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        // Second parameter is a primary key of the table
        $this->_init('Table_Name', 'id'); 
    }
}
```

**Step 3:** Create `Collection` file to initialize `Model` and `ResourceModel` files.

```
namespace <Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model\ResourceModel\Data;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;


class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            '<Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model\Data',
            '<Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model\ResourceModel\Data'
        );
    }
}
```

**Step 4:** Last thing that you need to do is create a `Block` file in the same module and utilize collection, something like this:

```
namespace <Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

use <Vendor_Name>\<Module_Name>\Model\Data as DataCollection;

class Custom_Module extends Template
{
    protected $dataCollection;

    public function __construct(Context $context, DataCollection $dataCollection)
    {
        $this->_dataCollection = $dataCollection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getDataCollecton()
    {
        $collection = $this->_dataCollection->getCollection();
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

---

### Another Solution

You can also use `fetchAll` instead of `fetch_assoc()` in Magento 2, if you don't want to implement `models` and `collections` based solution, something like this:

```
// Select Data from table
$sql = "Select * FROM " . $tableName;
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

and for reference, you can also have a look into [Magento2 – Write Custom Mysql Query (Without Using Model)](https://webkul.com/blog/magento2-write-custom-mysql-query/)

Answer (score 0):

In magento 2 you can use same but for that you need to create database connection.
I suggest you to use resource or collection models to get the result and if you want to get the first row in object format then you should use
getFirstItem();

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use something like below :

```
    $adapter = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection($resource);        
    $stmt = $adapter->query($sql);

    // Use FETCH_NUM so we are not dependent on the CASE attribute of the PDO connection
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(\Zend_Db::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Or if we have $connection instanceof \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface

```
    $connection->fetchAll($sql, $binds, \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

By using those, i think you're gonna get the same result to magento 1 fetch_assoc

Answer (score 0):

Alternative of the **fetch_assoc()** in magento 2 is **fetchAssoc($SQL_QUERY)**

Below is the example.

For get order where status is pending data using **fetchAssoc(SQL_QUERY)**

```
<?php
    namespace Path\To\Class;
    
    use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
    
    class fetchAssoc {
    
        const ORDER_TABLE = 'sales_order';
    
        /**
         * @var ResourceConnection
         */
        private $resourceConnection;
    
        public function __construct(
           ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
        ) {
           $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        }
    
        /**
        * fetchAssoc Sql Query
        *
        * @return string[]
        */
        public function fetchAssocQuery()
        {
          $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
          $tableName = $connection->getTableName(self::ORDER_TABLE);
    
          $query = $connection->select()
            ->from($tableName,['entity_id','status','grand_total'])
            ->where('status = ?', 'pending');
    
          $fetchData = $connection->fetchAssoc($query);
          return $fetchData;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Magento 2 has support for this in class \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface. You can create an instance for AdapterInterface by dependency injection or directly by object manager.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection */
$resourceConnection = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::class);

/** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface $connection */

$connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);

$sql = "YOUR SELECT QUERY HERE";
$data = $connection->fetchAssoc($sql);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).